# Does the SOQL Query Plan tool always do a table scan because of IsDeleted?

Tags: soql, developer-console, queryplan

I'm trying to use the Query Plan tool in the developer console for the first time.

Every single query that I try ends up with a table scan, because of the IsDeleted field not being indexed. The notes always have this for every table in the query:

```
Not considering filter for optimization because unindexed.
Table: Opportunity Fields: ["IsDeleted"]
```

Even if the query is as basic as:

```
select Id from Opportunity
where id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

[image]

And with queries with joins you end up with things like:

[image]

Is this normal ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It  only uses the lowest cost plan. Anything below that is irrelevant and can be safely ignored. So since your `Index` query has a `Cost` of **0.00001**, that's what the Query Optimizer will use at run time.

Note from [Query Plan Tool (How To & FAQ)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&type=1):

> **What does it all mean?**
>   The Query Plan tool will show a list of available plans that our Query Optimizer can utilize for the query provided and will be arranged by cost ascending. Each Plan will contain information on Cardinality, Operation Type, Cost, sObject Type, and more. Each plan has a “Leading Operation Type”, for example, Field Index or Full Table Scan. The plan with the lowest cost is the plan that is used for driving the query execution.

Comment: I guess that make sense, it is somewhat confusing though, telling you about options that it won't use and nagging you about IsDeleted not being indexed on every object

Comment: @andynormancx They're trying to get you more information. I'm sure if you were writing the tool, it would make sense why it works that way.

Comment: The appear to be giving me extra information that isn’t useful and I can do nothing about. What benefit does showing me table scans because of IsDeleted give me ? It isn’t as if I can add an index to IsDeleted. None of their example screenshots show the IsDeleted issue, which almost makes me wonder if showing it is a bug.

Comment: I'm getting similar with a QueryException - non-selective query. And yet all that I'm reading is saying the query should be selective as the result set is < 10% of the overall number of records. And when using the query plan too I'm also getting the message about IsDeleted. Incidently adding IsDeleted = false to your query results in the message being output twice. Definitely seems like a bug to me.